# obtain value from Key/value in map array groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jsr223

I have code like this:

```
def options = JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$.options')
def randomOption = options.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, options.size()))
def code = randomOption.get("code")
vars.put('code1', code)
def values = randomOption.get('values')
def randomValue = values.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, values.size())) as 
String
def val = randomValue['value']
vars.put('randomValue', randomValue)
vars.put('ValueF', val).
```

In Random Variable i am getting value as [label:Red, value:8] . I need to fetch the value of Value=8

Comment: `randomvariable.value`, `randomvariable['value']`, `randomvariable.get('value')` should all work.  What error do you get?

Comment: Got this error!  javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, [C) values: [ValueF, [label:Red, value:8]]

Comment: Your error states a `put` call and there is jmeter involved. You problem seems not just "how can i access a value in a map in groovy", but there is a bigger picture, you left out.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I have code like this:def options = JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$.options')
def randomOption = options.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, options.size()))
def code = randomOption.get("code")
vars.put('code1', code)
def values = randomOption.get('values')
def randomValue = values.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, values.size())) as String
def val = randomValue['value']
vars.put('randomValue', randomValue)
vars.put('ValueF', val). In Random Variable i am getting value as [label:Red, value:8] . I need to fetch the value of Value=8

Comment: Please add this to the question. Its quite hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Debug and see what you pass to `vars.put('code1', code)`. This method accepts two Strings, so it looks like `code` is not a String. Your problem is not reproducible. If you are not aware of types that are returned by functions you call, replace all `def` keywords with expected types, so you can get compilation errors with detailed information.

Comment: Why do you use `as String` when setting `randomValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Youre trying to invoke

```
vars.put('ValueF', [label:Red, value:8])
```

which is `put(String, Map)`

JMeterVariables have no such method https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html

you can use **putObject()** which accepts String as key and Object as value:

```
vars.putObject('ValueF', val)
```

Comment: Object is being saved insted of Value . ie 8 . I need value=8 on my variable 'ValueF'

Comment: ? Any inputs on my comments ?

Comment: You can access it something like: def objct = [value:8];vars.putObject('ValueF', objct);println(vars.getObject('ValueF').value). Or you can put only 8 to your vars like vars.put('ValueF', objct.value)

Comment: Could it be more specific , because i cannot use def objct = [value:8] w.r.t above code in Question!

Comment: vars.putObject('ValueF', [value: val.value])

Comment: Dint worked. Got this error again javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: [C

Comment: Can you provide output  println(val.dump()) ?

Comment: ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: [C
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: [C
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
 at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]

Comment: any luck on the above?

Comment: Provide output of following statement println(val.dump()) or  println(val.getClass())  please. Put it before line when you calling val.val

Comment: 2018-04-05 16:58:44,566 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: [C
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: [C .   This is the error i got